# .NET 5 and SPA Routing

Tags: c#, routes, vue-router, vuejs3, .net-5

I'm currently working with a .NET 5 application which implements a Vue JS front-end that uses Vue Router. I'm currently using the SpaStaticFilesExtension and am trying to Reroute to a page on the client, however I am being met with an error due to the .NET API not containing the Route I am trying to re-route to.

Below is my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "/";
            });
            ...
        }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = env.IsDevelopment() ? "/" : "/dist";

                if (env.IsDevelopment()) spa.UseVueCli();
            });
        }
```

Below is my attempt at routing to the client side-route.  Something to note is that I am calling this redirect in a controller which is attribute routed.  Furthermore, this controller routing DOES NOT exist on the Vue Router.

```
return RedirectToRoute("/some/Route/on/Spa", new routeVales{ routeVal1 = routeVal1 });
```

Below is my client-side code to match:

```
 {
      path: "/some/Route/on/Spa",
      name: "Name",
      component: SomeComponent
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectToRoute()` is used to redirect to a known route within ASP.Net. You just want to redirect to a URL so you can use `Redirect($"/some/Route/on/Spa/{routeVal1}")` instead.

Comment: You should be able to just append them in the string, like `Redirect($"/some/Route/on/Spa?routeVal1={WebUtility.UrlEncode(routeVal1)}")` (you might need to add the `System.Net` namespace to use WebUtility)